# Dart - How to check if a string contains every words from a search input?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to check if a string contains every words from an text input.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
String myString1 = "I love Flutter";
String myString2 = "I like Flutter";

String searchValue1 = "I flutter";
String searchValue2 = "I love flutter";

bool searchFunction(String myString, String searchValue) {
... // What I need to code
}
```

Expected result:

```
searchFunction(myString: myString1, searchValue1); //true
searchFunction(myString: myString2, searchValue1); //true
searchFunction(myString: myString1, searchValue2); //true
searchFunction(myString: myString2, searchValue2); //false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a shorter solution to this is

```
bool searchFunction(String myString, String searchValue) {
  if(myString == searchValue){
    return true;
  }
  int count = 0;
  var searchFor = searchValue.split(" ");
  for(final searchWord in searchFor){
    if(myString.contains(searchWord)){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count==searchFor.length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
void main() {
  String myString1 = "I love Flutter";
  String myString2 = "I like Flutter";

  String searchValue1 = "I flutter";
  String searchValue2 = "I love flutter";
  var b1 = searchFunction(myString1, searchValue1); //true
  print(b1);
  var b2 = searchFunction(myString2, searchValue1); //true
  print(b2);
  var b3 = searchFunction(myString1, searchValue2); //true
  print(b3);
  var b4 = searchFunction(myString2, searchValue2); //false
  print(b4);
}

bool searchFunction(String myString, String searchValue) {
  print("$myString , $searchValue");
  if (myString.toLowerCase() == searchValue.toLowerCase()) {
    return true;
  }

  var allWordsSearch = searchValue.split(" ");
  var allWords = myString.split(" ");
// has same count of words
  if (allWordsSearch.length == allWords.length) {
    //check every word
    bool allFound = true;
    allWordsSearch.forEach((element) {
      allFound &= searchValue.toLowerCase().contains(element);
    });

    return allFound;
  } else {
    int foundCount = 0;
    allWordsSearch.forEach((element) {
      foundCount++;
    });

    return foundCount >= allWordsSearch.length / 2; //50% of words match
  }
}
```